# Which adjective means "long unused"?

Tags: word-request

> I have been using Ubuntu operating system for a few years, and
>   recently I had to temporarily switch to my (long unused) Windows on the same laptop.

I wonder which adjective could be used instead to mean "long unused"? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As for one-word alternatives to the [cumulative adjective](http://grammar.about.com/od/c/g/Cumulative-Adjectives.htm) phrase “long unused”, **“Dusty”** can convey the same meaning metaphorically, assuming there are clues from context. The same goes for **“rusty”**, especially when referring to skills.

**“Dilapidated”** works best for buildings but can be extended to other things via metaphor and will generally indicate a *perceptible* state of disrepair. **“Decrepit”** is similar, but will carry overtones of the infirmities that come with aging for imperfectly self-replicating organisms (such as ourselves).

None of these necessarily conveys an especially long timeframe, and the latter two should be restricted to describing things that have suffered diminished structural integrity or aesthetic quality from disuse.

For the example sentence, I don’t think the substitution of any single word would add clarity.

Comment: Thanks! I wonder which adjective could be used instead to mean "long unused"?

Comment: I agree with "dusty", but your other proposals don't simply mean "unused" but indicate a state of disrepair. Something could be long unused but still be in excellent condition.

Comment: I believe my caveats made that distinction clear, but I’m happy to edit further.

Comment: On re-reading your post, yeah, you did acknowledge that, my comment was probably redundant.

Comment: I take it simply as an indication that I could have been more explicit with that point. Hopefully my latest edit makes the distinction between the first and second pairs of words more apparent.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a word that clearly expresses the idea. "Long unused" may be the best phrase. "Neglected" perhaps? "Abandoned"? "Idle"? (Though if you're talking about a computer, "idle" has a specific meaning in that context that may create an ambiguity.) "Moribund"? (Though I think that applies that it's almost dead or obsolete and not just unused.) You could use metaphors, like Tyler James Young's suggestion of "dusty", or "lonely".

Comment: Just saw the word "obsolete" in your post, and thought to myself, well, *my obsolete Windows on the same laptop* sounds quite right.

Comment: What about **hibernated** Windows PC? Out of many, one meaning of this word is *Be in an inactive or dormant state.*

Comment: Damkerng: But "obsolete" means that it is out of date and superseded by newer inventions. Something could be "long unused" without being obsolete. I have a spare mattress in my attic that I haven't used in several years, but it's still perfectly good, and I don't think mattress technology has advanced far enough in that time to make it obsolete.

Comment: Maulik: "Hibernate" has a specific technical meaning on Windows computers that would make this word possibly misleading.